# SQL Server connection C# : Authentication Windows to database uses computer name instead

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2012, windows-authentication

I have a problem connecting to my SQL Server Database, i should use a Windows Authentication, so i added `Integrated Security = true` in my connection string but i get the wrong identity. The program tries to open the connection to the database with the computer name instead of the session name. 
I get the error that the login is unknown in the Database, of course it's unknown it's not the good one.

Here is my connection string :

```
"Server=SERVER\DEV;Database=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=true"
```

(I replaced the true names of the server and the Database for confidentiality issues)

Here is the C# code:

```
private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];

public IList<string> GetAuthorizedGroupsForAJob(string jobId)
{
    IList<string> res = new List<string>();
    try
    {

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        //The error happens in the line below
        cnn.Open();
```

I searched for a while but everyone who gets the login error seems to forget the `Integrated Security=true` or `Trusted_Connection=true`.
Any help is welcomed here

Comment: So the account opening the connection is logged onto a Windows Domain server?

Comment: are the users setup in the database correctly?

Comment: @AlexK. : Yes, the account is logged onto a Windows domain server. the username should look like : domain\username while it looks like domain\computerName.

Comment: @TBridges : I can access the data base with my windows account outside of the code so i suppose it is set up correctly.

Comment: For windows credentials to work both the local PC and Server PC need to be in the same group.  If you are in a corporate network, the Group Policy needs updating.  Next you need a group account with all user added to group account (on both local a server PC).  Then the credentials of the database needs to be set to the windows group account.

Comment: I see, updating the Group Policy is a bit above me so i'll just contact my DB Administrator and see if we can't use a generic sql server account to connect instead of the Windows Authentication. As it seems impossible for now. That specification was helpful.

Comment: This is typical if the *calling* code is running under the `Network Service` special account - either because its running as a service or its running e.g. inside IIS in an application pool using that identity. If that's the case, you need to work out how to get impersonation set up so that the service/IIS application can assume the identity of whoever is calling *it*.

Answer (score 0):

Enable ASP.NET impersonation on IIS at the website level if you want the logged in user to reach your SQL server.

Comment: Please add more details like Configs and code changes.